# Input Columns with Awk

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, scripting

I'm trying to have the user enter a value to look at a specific column in a file. Is there a way to switch on columns with awk without having to repeat myself in all of the switch cases?

```
# Code:

read -p 'Enter a column:' input

for i in "$file_name"; do
  cat "$i" | awk -v column="$input" '{ print $column }'
done
```

Here's a better explanation:

```
view_column() {
  for i in "$file_name"; do
    cat "$i" | awk -v col="$1" '{ print $col }'
  done
}

print_menu() {
  menu=( 'First' 'Last' 'Email' 'Exit' )
  for (( i=0; i<${#menu[@]}; i++ )); do
    printf "%2d. %s\n" "$((i+1))" "${menu[$i]}"
  done
}

main() {
  while true; do 
    clear
    print_menu
    read -p 'Enter a choice: ' choice
    if (( "$choice" == 4 )); then
      break
    fi
    view_column "$choice"
    sleep 1.5
  done
}
```

Comment: is `$input` expected to be numeric?

Comment: Yes, input represents an integer. The file contains four fields that contain first name, last name, work hours, email. @hek2mgl

Comment: Then @Kent's answer should work, as your example

Comment: I came up with one solution in my re-edit, I just now can't figure out how to validate empty columns. @hek2mgl

Answer (score 2):

I am not 100% sure I understand your requirement right, does this work for you?

```
read -p 'Enter a column:' input
awk -v column="$input" '{ print $column }' $filename
```

Comment: The file I have is global so the code I have works, but I have a file that contains four fields: first, last, hours, and email. and I would like to switch on a choice. Based on the choice, I should get back the appropriate field output. I just couldn't figure out a way of doing that without repeating myself.

Comment: @user520720 sorry I don't get what is your problem.... :( you have 4 fields, you mean the case if user input 10 ? this needs to be checked?

Comment: I kind of came up with something in my head as to what I would like to accomplish. I re-edited my post.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that `awk "{ print \$$input }" $filename` would work as well.

Comment: I think I got it, see anything I could do better? @D.Shawley

Comment: You might consider posting or migrating this http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

This would work:

```
 read -p "Enter column [1-4] " i; echo One Two Three Four | awk '{print $'$i';}'
```

Note how `$i` is outside the single quotes (if you look closely), so it the shell interpolates the number if `$i` before executing the awk script, turning `'{print $'$i';}'` into `'print $3;}'` when `i == 3`.